# Are arrays in MongoDB documents always kept in order?

Tags: mongodb

I can find ample evidence that MongoDBs are always kept in the order given when a document is inserted or updated, but I just can't find it explicitly spelled out in the documentation for MongoDB.

So I'll go ahead and ask the [probably stupid] question: are arrays in MongoDB documents kept in the order specified when they were inserted/updated?

And sharding/replication/etc. do *not* effect this ordering, correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do arrays stored in MongoDB keep their order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013916/do-arrays-stored-in-mongodb-keep-their-order)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are speaking about the **order of an array value of a document field**, then yes the order is always kept. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013916/do-arrays-stored-in-mongodb-keep-their-order).

If you speak about the order of documents in a collection, to my knowledge you shouldn't count on any order. If you need an order, you should implement your own `created_at` or `sequence_index` field.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking about the order of an array on a document. That question looks like a duplicate, thanks for finding it! Do you have a reference besides that stackoverflow post? For instance, something in a spec, the MongoDB docs, their mailing list, etc? https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongodb-user/HfFlSInmZME/discussion seems like the best lead so far.