# Does mongo db ListField maintain ordering?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

If I add items to a ListField on a mongo db document in a specific order and then write it to the database, is it guaranteed that all subsequent reads will see the list in the same order?

e.g.
write

```
obj = MyDocument.by_id(id)
obj.list_field = []
obj.list_field.add("a");
obj.list_field.add("b");
obj.list_field.add("c");
obj.save()
```

read

```
obj = MyDocument.by_id(id)
for x in obj.list_field:
    print(x)

# will it always print in this order?
# a
# b
# c
```

this is using python mongoengine ORM v0.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they do, the driver is faithful to the underlying data and mongoDb guarantees this ([Do arrays stored in MongoDB keep their order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013916/do-arrays-stored-in-mongodb-keep-their-order))

Comment: thanks. I'll vote to close this as duplicate