# sails.js mongodb rest api update issue

Tags: json, mongodb, sails.js

I am new to sails.js and mongodb. I found something strange. When i use rest api to update the record in mongodb, after record updated, the json format changed.

For example. Originally I have a record like this:

{
creator: "John",
taskname: "test",
id: "53281a5d709602dc17b000cd"
}

After clicking http://127.xxx:1337/testtask/update/53281a5d709602dc17b000cd?creator=default%20creator, following json returned.

The json field is sorted in alphabetic order.

How can i keep the origin format of the json file? Is it a bug? Is there any workaround?

{
createdAt: "2014-03-18T10:05:17.052Z",
creator: "default creator",
taskname: "test",
updatedAt: "2014-03-18T10:08:53.067Z",
id: "53281a5d709602dc17b000cd"
}

Thanks.

Comment: Looks more like a **"feature"**. You are using something else with node, an ODM or other framework of some sort. Possibly Sails? Meteor? That isn't in your question tags.

Comment: Using sails.js on top of node.js with sails-mongo adaptor to connect to mongo db. If it is a "feature", could it be configurable in some where so that I could keep the format of json after updating? I am using window platform so I give up using Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

Much like the "other" framework that inspired this, there is some automatic time-stamp generation happening in your models when things are updated or created. You wouldn't be the first. Ruby people have been trapped by this for years.

There are [options](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline#options) you can define on your collection objects to remove these fields. This comes from the Waterline documentation, which should be the manager in use.

So in addition to attributes:

```
autoCreatedAt: false,
autoUpdatedAt: false,

attributes: {
   // normal things here
},
```

Of course you will need to remove any of these properties that have been created in your documents manually. See the [`$unset`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/#up._S_unset) operator for doing this

Comment: tried. However, it doesn't work. The createdAt and updatedAt no longer automatically created. However, the same, once updated using REST API, the fields inside json file automatically sorted. Any option parameter available so that I can stop this sorting behavior??

Comment: @user3432583 Sorry I gave you the wrong syntax to configure in the model. Changed above and yes I actually tested it this time.

Comment: Thanks. however, setting the autocreateat and autoupdateat to false cannot solve my original problem - that is keep the ordering of the json file after restful update. Do you encounter same problem in your test?

Comment: @user3432583 Not really because I would be using **POST** with the JSON in the body. Then the JSON stays in order. But `id` is always last in the waterline (mongo) implementation. Passing parameters in **GET** is always going to yield unexpected results. And is not strictly RESTful. So you should be doing the correct RESTful things.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fields in JSON objects don't have any concept of order.  A JSON object is a [dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), or in other words just some key/value pairs. This means that this JSON:

```
{ "a" : "some string", "b" : "other string" }
```

is logically equivalent to this JSON:

```
{ "b" : "other string", "a" : "some string" }
```

If you want to preserve ordering in your JSON data there are other ways to do it.  For example JSON arrays do preserve order so something like this would work:

```
[  { "a" : "some string" }, { "b" : "other string" } ]
```

Internally MongoDB may actually preserve the ordering, but that's an implementation detail and you can't depend on it.

More detail on what Mongo is doing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576823/can-mongodb-and-its-drivers-preserve-the-ordering-of-document-elements).

Comment: Actually JSON and mongo by order of using BSON **does** maintain order. That is why it is required in some language implementations to use an **ordered** hashing scheme that may not be the default as some mongo operations require this order to be maintained. The problem here is **extra** unexpected fields being inserted, and they are inserted into the structure in that order.

Comment: BSON is superset of JSON and has capabilities JSON doesn't have.  The question show sending JSON to mongo via HTTP, so there is no concept of order in this case.  Any side effects you notice about creat vs update are implementation details and cannot be relied on.  If you want BSON you have to explicitly use that format.

Comment: Read again. Realize why the answer was given. Then go try **your theory** yourself. Insert some JSON and see if MongoDB **ever** re-arranges the order of the data as you have inserted it. When you get that result, then feel free to submit it as a bug. Yes the "fields" are sent over http request and yes they *could* come out of order, however there is only **one** field present before the update other than the required id, using **sails**, all of a sudden, two more fields appear, and they mess up the **order**. It's how **sails** does things by default. The answer is to **change** that.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work like that, I'm saying it's an implementation detail specific to BSON.  If you're targeting that fine, it you are only targeting JSON and the general concept on document oriented DBs then I would not recommend designing based on field order of dictionaries.