# pymongo update location data

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, geolocation

I want to update an  array containing lat,lng values.my update query from python is given below.

```
client.mydb.mycoll.update({"_id":123},{'$push':{"loc":{"lng":77.77,"lat":12.12}}} )
```

the collection already have some value in "loc" array as follows

```
{ "_id" : 123, "loc" : [    {   "lng" : 77.6104193,     "lat" : 12.9264116 } ], "name" : "myname" }
```

the problem with update query is that it store the new "loc" element as

> { "_id" : 123, "loc" : [   {   "lng" : 77.6104193,     "lat" : 12.9264116 },{"lat":12.12,"lng":77.77} ], "name" : "myname" }

I need to store loc data in the order "lng" fist and then "lat".so that later, I can  query using $near operator ({loc:{$near:[77.77,12.12]}}).python dictionary always store key value pair sorted according to key.how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) in python doc.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

client.mydb.mycoll.update({"_id":123},{'$push':{"loc":OrderedDict((("lng",77.77),("lat":12.12)))}} )
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing the structure slightly to match that from the [MongoDB manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/):

```
coordinates : [ <longitude> , <latitude> ]
```

so you'll end up with something like this:

```
{ "_id" : 123, "loc" : [ [77.6104193, 12.9264116], [77.77, 12.12] ], "name" : "myname" }
```

MongoDB keeps the order of the array, but does not guarantee preserving the order of object's fields ([See this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8577139/467435)).

Comment: I can't do that,because there is already data in the table using php code.I am moving from php to python